# Read a line using Pointer variable in C

Tags: c

[Code]

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>  // getch()
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char c, *s;
    printf("Enter the number...\n");
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {
        putchar(c);
        *s++ = c;    // **What is wrong in here, the code is crashing!!**
    }

    printf("The number: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> c:\works\workout\c>gcc tmp.c -o tmp
>
> c:\works\workout\c>tmp
>
> Enter the number...
>
> 434232
>
> 4
>
> c:\works\workout\c>

**Expected Output:**
The actual given input number/string!  (e.g 434232 in here)

Expecting output by using 'pointer' only (Without using 'scanf', 'char s[10]' etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `s` point to in the memory? It is just capable of pointing to a single `char` in your code. Did you forget a dynamic memory allocation on `s`?

Comment: `c` should be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Yes, Initially we're pointing to the start address of 's', then we're trying to increment by '1'. Is it actually needed to first allocate the no. of memory block at first? PL correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JaiK You could be accessing memory which is not yours when you are doing that incrementation. You should first reserve enough memory by using `malloc` or something like that.

Comment: @Barmar Still, crashing.  `int c; char *s;`

Comment: @JaiK Because you forgot to allocate memory for `s` as the first comment said.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to allocate `s` because it is a pointer.

Secondly, declare `int c` instead of `char c` because the definition of the functions `getchar()` and `putchar()` as:

```
 int putchar(int c); 
 int getchar(void);
```

Finally, Use `s[i] = ...` instead of `*s++ =`.

The complete code (In this code, i use the `realloc` function for allocating each time you get new value from keyboard):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int c;
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);
    if (s == NULL)
       exit(-1);
    printf("Enter the number...\n");
    int i = 0;
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {
        putchar(c);
        s[i] = c; 
        // re-allocate because the size of s has to increase to store the new value
        s = realloc(s, sizeof(char));
        if (s == NULL)
           exit(-1);
        i++;
    }

    printf("The number: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: s should be checked for NULL after callling realloc (and malloc).